# How to apply Spring Cloud Gateway GlobalFilter on WebClient in a RouterFuncation bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

Currently I am trying to use Spring Cloud Gateway(Spring Cloud version: Finchley.M5) in a edge-service, my sample has a Spring Session header(**X-AUTH-TOKEN**) token based authentication.

1. In Gateway specific `RouteLocator`, the authentication works well, because the built-in GlobalFilters are applied on the `RouteLocator` when it passes request to downstream microservice.
2. But I want to create a generic `RouterFunction` to consume some resources of downstream  services and aggregate them together in a new edgeservice, the GlobalFileters will not apply on my `webclient` bean.

   ```
   @Bean
   RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(WebClient webClient) {
   log.debug("authServiceUrl:{}", this.authServiceUrl);
   log.debug("postServiceUrl:{}", this.postServiceUrl);
   log.debug("favoriteServiceUrl:{}", this.favoriteServiceUrl);

   return route(
       GET("/posts/{slug}/favorited"),
       (req) -> {
           Flux<Map> favorites = webClient
               .get()
               .uri(favoriteServiceUrl + "/posts/{slug}/favorited", req.pathVariable("slug"))
               .retrieve()
               .bodyToFlux(Map.class);

           Publisher<Map> cb = from(favorites)
               .commandName("posts-favorites")
               .fallback(Flux.just(Collections.singletonMap("favorited", false)))
               .eager()
               .build();

           return ok().body(favorites, Map.class);
       }
   )
   ...
   ```

Is there a simple solution to apply Gateway Filter also work on the  `RouterFunction`, thus my header token based authentication can work automatically?

Or there is a simple way to pass current **X-AUTH-TOKEN** header into the downstream webclient request headers?

In traditional MVC, there is a `RequestContext` used to get all headers from current request context and pass them to the downstream request in a global filter. Is there an alternative of `RequestContext`  in webflux to read all headers from current request context?

The complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-microservice-sample/tree/master/gateway).

Comment: Global Filters do not apply to web client or router function beans

Comment: @spencergibb I see. May be I could ask how to pass current **X-AUTH-TOKEN** header to the downstream webclient request.

Comment: you have the request right there `req`. Grab the header out and add it to the `WebClient` manually.

Comment: I have tried this, but this can be only applied on a certain route(via webClient **matute().filter(<filter here>).build()**). What I need is if there is a global filter add to webClient **globally**?

Comment: I think there is a web client builder that is a bean you can manipulate

Comment: @spencergibb The things blocked me is how to transfer the request context(such as **token** header in my sample) to downstream service. In traditional MVC, it is easy to get it. But in the **reactive** mode, I can not find a good approach to archive this purpose.

Comment: get the from the `req` object and add them to the `webClient` call?